# Scaner nextInt() - Shall I handle the InputMismatchException thrown by this method when user enters something other than integer?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

While using the nextInt() method of Scanner class, if InputMismatchException is being thrown, shall I handle that by catch block ?
It's a runtime exception, but caused by user input and not programmer's mistake.

Here is my code.

```
package com.sample.programs;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        readInteger();
    }

    private static void readInteger() {
        // Created a Scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Display a prompt text
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer");

        // Accept the input from user
        int number;
        try {
            number = input.nextInt();
            // Display the output to user
            System.out.println("You entered: " + number);
        } catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
            System.err.println("You have entered wrong input. Please enter a number");
            // Log the stack trace
            readInteger();
        } finally {
            input.close();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You'd better handle it if you don't want your program to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Is better to handle the user wrong input beacouse you cannot control or be sure that the user will aligned data correctly, and you cannot read doubles, or strings with readInteger(). 
So I will handle the exception.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should call [`hasNextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) before calling [`nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29).

The exception truly means programmer error, since the programmer forgot to check validity before calling the method.

If you then want to prompt the user again, remember to discard the bad input first.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int value;
for (;;) {
    System.out.println("Enter number between 1 and 10:");
    if (! input.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("** Not a number");
        input.nextLine(); // discard bad input
        continue; // prompt again
    }
    value = input.nextInt();
    if (value < 1 || value > 10) {
        System.out.println("** Number must be between 1 and 10");
        input.nextLine(); // discard any bad input following number
        continue; // prompt again
    }
    if (! input.nextLine().trim().isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("** Bad input found after number");
        continue; // prompt again
    }
    break; // we got good value
}
// use value here

// don't close input
```